# Toggle div created in a for cycle

Tags: javascript, jquery, symfony, twig

I'm trying to code a script to toggle a dynamically created `<div>`.

Each `<div>` must have his own button to toggle.

The code is in a `.twig` file (Symfony project).

This is my script:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
$( function () {
    $('#toggle').click(
        function () {
            $("#explanation").fadeToggle("fast");
        });
    });
</script>
```

This is the code within the for cycle:

```
<div>
    <a id="toggle" class="tip maximize-all" data-toggle="tip" data-title="Maximize All"
        href="javascript:void(0);">
        {% trans %} details {% endtrans %}
    </a>
</div>

<div id="explanation" style="display: none;">
    Hello world!
</div>
```

I need help in coding the script not for the loop.

Comment: seems to work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/7UhAP/

Comment: I think the OP is planning to add div's in a loop and needs to be able to interact with them.

Comment: Please simplify the question to identify the problem fully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the right code using Bootstrap, Symfony, Twig:

```
<div class="accordion" id="collapse-group">
    <a data-parent="#collapse-group" href="#collapse{{ loop.index }}" data-toggle="collapse">
                            Label_Button
    </a>
    <div class="collapse" id="collapse{{ loop.index }}">
        Text
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use classes, rather than id's, because you cannot have duplicate id's in a page. I made those changes here -

```
<div>
    <a class="toggle" class="tip maximize-all" data-toggle="tip" data-title="Maximize All"
        href="javascript:void(0);">
        {% trans %} details {% endtrans %}
    </a>

</div>

<div class="explanation" style="display: none;">
    Hello world!
</div>
```

Now you can change your jQuery to this, using DOM traversal to find the right div -

```
<script language="JavaScript">
$( function () {
    $('body').on('click', '.toggle', 
        function () {
            $(this).parent().next('.explanation').fadeToggle('fast');
        });
    });
</script>
```

That way you can handle all of the toggle / explanation pairs with just a few lines including any div's that you add to the DOM dynamically using event delegation `on()`.